# Incrementing a class variable from a method in Java

Tags: java

I am working on a Java project and I am stuck in this simple class.
Basically, I am trying to call the "add" method from another class, and then use the incremented "WaterAmount" integer as a JProgressBar value.Now my problem is:

every time I call the "add" method, the "WaterAmount" integer stays at 0 and the progress bar has a value of 0.
However, if I set the "WaterAmount" manually, it works.
So what am I missing here, why doesn't the "add" method increment the "WaterAmount" integer??

Here is my code:

```
public class Water {

int WaterAmount;

public void add(int amountA) {

WaterAmount = WaterAmount + amountA;


}

 public void remove(int amountR) {

 WaterAmount = WaterAmount - amountR;

}

}
```

To call the "add" method I use:

```
Water water = new Water();
water.add(10);
```

And to read the "WaterAmount" value in the other class i use:

```
    public void updateDisplay() {

    waterAmount.setValue(water.WaterAmount);
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    Main system = new Main();

   system.updateDisplay();
    }
```

"waterAmount" is lowercase and it is the name of my progress bar

Comment: Do you create new `Water` object for each call to `water.add()`?

Comment: No, I use only one object

Comment: @BlockCoder Can you add how you read the `WaterAmount` value? The code you showed works just fine.

Comment: Could it be because my progress bar is the same name as the "WaterAmount" but only lowercase??

Comment: @BlockCoder No that's not possible. Are you sure you call `waterAmount.setValue(water.WaterAmount)` after you called the `.add()`/`remove()`?

Comment: Yes, i just checked

Comment: If you still not find the answer, Can you post the `add` method that you are calling.

Comment: @BlockCoder what are you getting calling a `System.out.print(water.WaterAmount)`after `water.add(10);`

Comment: When I run System.out.print(water.WaterAmount), I get 5,10,15,20... because I set it to add 5 every time. (I actualy add 5 in my code  10 was just an example)

Answer (score 0):

Run this simple test and understand the way reference variables work in java

```
public class Water {

    int WaterAmount;

    public int getWaterAmount() {
        return WaterAmount;
    }

    public void setWaterAmount(int waterAmount) {
        WaterAmount = waterAmount;
    }

    public void add(int amountA) {
        WaterAmount = WaterAmount + amountA;
    }

    public void remove(int amountR) {
        WaterAmount = WaterAmount - amountR;
    }
}
```

Create a Test class

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Water wat = new Water();
        wat.add(10);
        System.out.println( wat.getWaterAmount());
    }
}
```

Output
10

Answer (score 0):

your problem isn't with the Water class, it's with the way you are associating Water.WaterAmount with the ProgressBar.  You're assuming that ProgressBar is watching for changes in value of WaterAmount (e.g. that the ProgressBar value is bound to the WaterAmount value), but it simply isn't.  The value of WaterAmount is certainly increasing every time you call add(), but the value of the progressBar won't change.

Trivially, you need to call progressBar.setValue() every time the value of waterAmount changes.  How to best do that depends on information you're not showing us (what calls water.add(10) and what, if any, threads are you using)

Comment: The water.add() method is called from an" actionPerformed" method (every time a button is pressed).And the progressBar.setValue() is called in the main method, I even tried putting the progressBar.setValue() in a while loop but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I forgot to place the "system.updateDisplay()" inside a loop.
Thanks for all your help.

Comment: that is the reason you should place imp part of your code here!

Answer (score -1):

Use 'this'.. Try this.w=this.w+ amount ;